# How do I register an mysql database?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for a noob question regarding MySQL. I downloaded [FlightStats](http://dl.flightstats.us/) to learn about mysql but I can't figure out how to register it with my localhost mysql db. I know in MS SQL you can simply register any sql db using sql studio. I tried to google but come up with no result. Perhaps, my search phrase is wrong. I'm searching with "how to register a mysql database, register a mysql database...etc.". How do you register or setup an database from existing database like FlightStats? I'm using DBVisualizer. Is there a way in dbVis that I'm not aware of to regsiter a database?

Thanks

edit: sorry for the bad wording. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files). I have the .myd, .myi and .frm and I want to get it to restore(?) with my local mysql instance. I look at all the answers but I'm still confuse as how you restore the database from those 3 files.

Comment: what does register mean?

Comment: Just for clarifications sake. You register an MS SQL instance in Management Studio rather than a database, an instance often holds more than one database.

Comment: @kerchingo Yes, you're correct. I want to add the database that i've downloaded which contain .frm, .myd and .myi into my local mysql instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little background first. The FlightStats download page linked to in the original question appears to provide zipped tarballs of the binary table storage files from the MySQL data directory. <s>Given that this is considered a viable means of distribution, and combined with the use of MERGE tables, I would surmise that this tarball contains a bunch of MyISAM data files (`.myi`, `.myd`).</s> Jack's edit confirms that this is the situation.

This is an atypical means of distributing a MySQL data set, although not at all uncommon when backing up MyISAM storage, and probably not all that unheard of for moving large data sets around; it likely works out considerably more space-efficient than a corresponding dump file. Of course, in SQL Server land, it's pretty common to attach database files into an instance.

Broadly speaking, you'd recover the database as follows:

1. Locate the MySQL data directory; typically `/var/mysql` or similar
2. Create a new directory with the desired database name e.g. `flightdata`
3. Extract the `.myi`, `.myd` and other files from the tarball into this directory
4. Make sure the entire directory is owned by the user MySQL runs as (usually `mysql`) - use `chmod -R` to make sure you get everything
5. Open a MySQL console
6. `USE <database-name>`
7. `SHOW TABLES`

You should see some tables listed. In addition, the downloads page linked includes a couple of SQL scripts, which contain SQL commands that you need to run against your database once it's in place. These will cause the merge definitions and table indexes to be rebuilt. You can pipe these into the command-line client, e.g. `mysql -u<username> -p<password> <database-name> < <sql-file>`.

It may be a good idea to shut down the MySQL server while you're doing this; use e.g. `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` or similar, and restart once the files are extracted in place.

Answer (score -2):

There's generally a way to import sql files using a GUI database tool.  I'm not familiar with DBVisualizer, but as long as you have a MySQL command line client installed you can do it there as well.  It's pretty easy:

1. Create a blank schema.  You can do this in your GUI tool or on the command line client.  Just use `CREATE DATABASE flightstats;`, or whatever name you want.
2. Use the following command line syntax to import/run an sql file on the new schema:  `mysql -u <username> -p flightstats < /path/to/file.sql`

The `-p` option prompts for a password.  I generally set up the database using step 1 as the root user, then `GRANT` some permissions on it to a new user id, then use that user id to run the SQL file.

This process is pretty much what a GUI tool will do in the background.

Answer (score -2):

Registering a database? dont know what that means however mysql gui tools can help you creating a database. Have a look at it or better you download phpmyadmin.[image]

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Google WAMP for Windows.

Google MAMP for Mac.

Google LAMP for Linux.

Any questions?

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I think you misunderstand my question.