# How to export a MySQL database (data folder) from an hard disk?

Tags: mysql, export, restore

I know, it is really sad trying to export a database just by copying the data folder! But I have a hard disk with an important database inside and I don't know how to export this database onto my actual system (winxp - mysql 5.0.37).

So, i've copied old_harddisk/program/mysql/data/coge2010 to mypc/programs/mysql/data/coge2010

Result:

- I see cogemilla (4) on my phpMyAdmin databases summary (it's correct!!! my 4 tables!)
- If I click the database, I see just 1 table (oh no!)
- On the mysql error log file I find messages like this one: *"...[ERROR] Cannot find table coge2010/soci from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html how you can resolve the problem."*

Any ideas?

Comment: try recreating the schema alone. It might be an error because of schema unavailability.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a dump and import it on the new server.

In Command Prompt type the following to create the dumpfile:

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -p databaseName > dumpFile.sql
```

To import the database :

```
mysql -h host -u user -p databaseName < dumpFile.sql
```

Comment: the database is on an old laptop harddisk (the laptop is dead)

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files) may help you.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files) which may help you.

A mysql table is defined by 3 files (FRM/MYD/MYI). In your case the FRM file is missing into the database folder.

If you can run the mysql server of the old hard disk it is easier to do a dump of your database. [The following link](http://www.patrickpatoray.com/?Page=30) shows you how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can only copy InnoDB tables if:
1. Your database is stopped.
2. You copy all InnoDB files (ibdata* ib_logfile* /*.ibd

You could use dump/restore to copy a single table.

You could user 'ALTER TABLE sometable ENGINE=MyISAM' to convert it to MyISAM and then copy the MYI,MYD and FRM.

Percona XtraBackup can do single table restores if you're using Percona Server.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution,
I connected the hard disk with the old table.
Changed a value inside the file my.ini on (c:\ProgramData\MySQL{server}) from

```
datadir=current-path-data
```

to the path in the harddisk (in my case just change the c:\ to d:\ )

Reset the MySQL service WINKEY+R -> services.msc -> click restart.
[my SQL service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJpP.png)

Entered the workbench and all old the table was there, after I dumped all the table via the data export function.
Changed back the my.ini to the local disk reset the Mysql service path and imported the data to the correct table.
Worked like a charm.