# Access mysql database from a different installation

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have a hard drive with an old Ubuntu Server installation running mysql that got bad sectors and isn't accessible anymore. Luckily I was able to create a snapshot of this drive before it died and now I am able to MOUNT it in my new Ubuntu installation as a second hard drive, it still has all the files, binaries and everything on it.

So here's my problem, I really need to dump that mysql database from that snapshot. is it possible to somehow log in into the snapshot's drive mysql and dump it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this post might be your answer:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/backing-up-and-restoring-mysql-databases/5259660

> Find and copy over the contents of mysql's data/ directory.

Having a quick look on my Ubuntu server though I can't immediately find a data/ directory, but I do have all my databases and data files in /var/lib/mysql, so check there as well.

running the following command as root / admin user in the terminal will give you a list of places to start looking

```
find / -name "mysql"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to restore it from the /var/lib/mysql, more details for anyone else that runs into this problem can be found at this post as well [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files)