# Recover Deleted MySQL Row?

Tags: mysql, recover

I've deleted some rows by mistake. I have MYD, FRM and MYI files. When I check MYD file I can see deleted records. I got copies of that 3 files right after deleted.

How do I recover deleted rows in MYD file?

Comment: Restore from backups. You *have* backups, right?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files

Answer (score 0):

restore from backups, and in the worst case [seek professional help](http://www.percona.com/mysql-consulting/data-recovery/). also take a look [here](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24119).

do not make any modifications to the disk where data is stored. if you want to play around it - image it first.