# How to create a sql file from MySQL command line client

Tags: mysql

I have created a database using MySQL command line client. All database files in *.frm format. Now I want to create a *.sql file from tables of this database. How to do this ?
I have fond some similar questions here and none of the solutions provided worked for me.

Comment: Are you attempting to recover your database from your `.frm` files, or you just want `.sql` files created? If the latter, check out [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). If the former, then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files

Comment: @newfurniturey Thanks for the information. I just wanted to export my database as a *.sql file and I did it as Mihai Iorga said. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database > /path/to/file/database.sql
```

where `root` is username and you will be prompted for password, `database` is database name

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First we need to change the directory to MySQL>>bin then we can run mysqldump

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqldump to export the database.

```
mysqldump MyDatabase > MyDatabase.sql
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Where I need to execute these command?? In windows command prompt or MySQL command line client ?? I tried to execute this in MySQL command line client and it gives a syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select your table whose .sql file you want to create -> then click on Export -> then press Go. .SQL file of that table will be created