# Where does MySQL store database files on Windows and what are the names of the files?

Tags: mysql, database, windows

I accidentally formatted my hard drive and re-installed Windows and forgot to backup an important database I had in my MySQL server. I'm trying to salvage files now using some software, but I don't know what to look for.

What is the path that the files are stored in, and what are the files named (what naming convention, or file extension should I look for)?

I believe my server was using MyISAM, but not 100% sure.

Comment: file extension is `.sql`

Comment: not sure but I always backup C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data this folder before formating

Comment: I would have just exported my tables to .sql if I remembered, but since I haven't used the database in a long time, I completely forgot about it

Comment: @Mr.Alien - not `.sql`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can check `my.ini` file to see where the data folder is located.

Usually there is a folder {mysqlDirectory}/data

MySQL data storage:

```
Commands.frm
Commands.myd
Commands.myi
```

The *.frm files contain the table definitions. Your *.myi files are MyISAM index files. Your *.myd files contain the table data.

**Edit/Update**. 
Because of the interest shown in the question here is more info which is found also in the comments.

In Windows 8.1, the MySQL databases are stored (by default) here: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data`

The folder C:\ProgramData is a hidden folder, so you must type it into Windows Explorer address to get there. In that data folder, the databases are named `/{database_name_folder}/{database_tables_and_files}`.

For instance,

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydatabase\mytable.frm
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydatabase\mytable.ibd
```

Thank @marty-mcgee for this content

Comment: this (.myd) is only for MyISAM engine. For InnoDB you need to see "ibdata1" file placed on the "{mysqlDirectory}/".

Comment: can I copy this data/mydatabase folder from another PC to mine? For some reason the sql import (using WAMP) is INCREDIBLY SLOW, but not on the other PC. I am thinking of copying its data folder

Comment: why don't you use mysql_dump?

Comment: In Windows 8.1, the MySQL databases are stored (by default) here: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data` -- this folder `C:\ProgramData` is a hidden folder, so you must type it into Windows Explorer address to get there. In that data folder, the databases are named `/{database_name_folder}/{database_tables_and_files}`. For instance, `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydatabase\mytable.frm` and `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydatabase\mytable.ibd`

Comment: Marty-McGee's comment above should be answer for people using InnoDB. I almost missed his solution since it was in a comment.

Comment: can anyone help me how to open that database folder in mysql workbench

Answer (score 42):

In Windows 7, the MySQL database is stored at

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

Note: this is a *hidden* folder. And my example is for MySQL Server version 5.6; change the folder name based on your version if different.

It comes in handy to know this location because sometimes the MySQL Workbench fails to drop schemas (or import databases). This is mostly due to the presence of files in the db folders that for some reason could not be removed in an earlier process by the Workbench. Remove the files using Windows Explorer and try again (dropping, importing), your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 20):

I have a default my-default.ini file in the root and there is one server configuration:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

So that does not tell me the path.

The best way is to connect to the database and run this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir" ;
```

Here's the result of that:

```
basedir                     C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\
character_sets_dir          C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\

datadir                     C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_log_group_home_dir   .\
lc_messages_dir             C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\

plugin_dir                  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\

slave_load_tmpdir           C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
tmpdir                      C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
```

If you want to see all the parameters configured for the database execute this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

The storage_engine variable will tell you if you're using InnoDb or MyISAM.

Comment: No, that will tell you the default.  You need to use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check a specific table.  And different tables can use different Engines.

Answer (score 11):

MYSQL 8.0:

Search `my.ini` in disk, we will find this folder:

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
>   It's `ProgramData`, not `Program file`

Data is in sub-folder: `\Data`.

Each `database` owns a folder, each `table` is file, each `index` is 1+ files.

Here is a sample database `sakila`:
[image]

Comment: can you help me how to open the sakila db in the mysql workbench. I am having difficulty on this.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows7 Use This Link:
c:\users\all users\MySql\MySql Server x.x\Data\

Where x.x is the version number of the sql server installed in your machine.

Answer (score 4):

That should be your {install path}\data e.g. `C:\apps\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\{databasename}`

- [How to recover MySQL database from .myd, .myi, .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files)
- [MySQL directory structure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpm7/m7dirstruct.html)
- [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)

Answer (score 4):

Just perform a Windows Search for *.myi files on your local partitions. Period.

As I suspectected, they were located inside a program files folder, instead of using a proper data-only folder like most other database managers do.

Why do a my.ini file search, open it with an editor, look-up the path string, make sure you don't alter the config file (!), and then do a second search? Complicated without a shred of added benefit other than to practice touch typing.

Comment: Picked this one because it is fast and simple.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Win10 with Xampp server installed, then you can find the data folder in **C:\xampp\mysql\data**

Inside the data folder, each database has its own folder which in turn contains the .frm, .myi and .myd files which represent for a single table in the database.

If for instance, you created a database with the name: myschool and inside the database, you have three tables with the names:

1. Nursery
2. Primary
3. Secondary

Then, you will have  for the Nursery table: nursery.frm, nursery.myi and nursery.myd. Same will go for the Primary and Secondary tables. Thus, in the I mentioned here, you will a total of 9 files inside the database folder named **myschool**.

You can then copy the database folder and use it in your new mysql installation data folder.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually in the folder specified below, but ProgramData is usually a hidden folder. To show it, go to control panel search for "folder" then under advanced settings tick show hidden files and click apply.
C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/

Answer (score 2):

I just installed MySQL 5.7 on Windows7. The database files are located in the following directory which is a hidden one:
`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data`

The `my.ini` file is located in the same root: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL are 
".myd" a database self and 
".tmd" a temporal file.
But sometimes I see also ".sql".

It depends on your settings and/or export method.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 , MySQL 8.0 Follow the below procedure to get the databases:

step 1:go to **localdisk(c)** if you find **ProgramData** the follow the below path to get the databases:

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data

Step 2: go to **localdisk(c)** click on **view**.

Step 3: click on hidden files and select then you will see ProgramData and then follow the step 1 then you get the databases

Here you can follow this:

[click on this link you will get visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYdYM.png)

Answer (score 0):

1) Locate the my.ini, which store in the MySQL installation folder.

For example,

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini
```

2) Open the “my.ini” with our favor text editor.

```
#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"

#Path to the database root/"
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data
```

Find the “datadir”, this is the where does MySQL stored the data in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\sys**

paste `URL`in to window file,
and get `Tables, Procedures, Functions` from this directory