# MySQL: Check If Table's Data Has modified Without trigger and UDF?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to know if a MySQL table's data has been modified?

Comment: Perhaps add a `modified_date` column and update it with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/307438/2088851 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chat with @Voitcus, we figured out, that the `information_schema` approach isn't available for `InnoDb` tables. The column `UPDATE_TIME` will being `NULL` for such tables.

That's why we worked out a solution for `InnoDB` tables that does not require read access to the db file on hard disk (what I think would be a security issue and no admin should allow this, also the db server could be on a different host)

Solution:

As you said, that you cannot use trigger functions for this, you'll have to fix this on application level, in PHP. **Update**: Note that with current versions of MySQL it wouldn't be stable to use triggers anyway as they won't get called on cascading foreign key actions.

First create a table, let's say `stats`:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourdb`.`stats` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `table_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `last_update` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Insert a row for every table in your application.

In PHP modify existing queries so that they use transactions and update the stats table. This is possible using `mysqli` or `PDO` for example. I'm using `PDO` here, we deleting a row for example.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($host, $user, $pass, $db, array((
        // this option is nice when working with transactions
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('cannot connect to mysql');
}


try {
    // start transaction
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    // delete a row
    $pdo->query('DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = 1');
    // update stats
    $pdo->query('UPDATE `stats` SET `last_update` = NOW() WHERE `table_name` = `table1`');
    // commit both queries at once
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // rollback both queries if one of them failed
    $pdo->rollback();
}
```

Now you can use the following query to obtain the last update time:

```
SELECT `last_updated` FROM `stats` WHERE `table_name` = 'table1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database, table [`TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) and there is a column "UPDATE_TIME". ([`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-tables.html) is somewhat equivalent).

The other way is to give the PHP access to db files (if you can locate them) and check system date of file modification. **EDIT** read permission is enough for this operation.

Comment: nice answer +1 (at least the first part ;) I'm not sure if PHP should have access to the db files.

Comment: PHP has access if you grant, it's running as root/administrator etc. To get what files to look check eg. [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12947668/2088851). This is of course some workaround; I'm not sure if `SHOW TABLES` has UPDATE_TIME field in every db engine.

Comment: No, I just wanted to point out that it could be a potential risk, to let php have access to the files. However, `information_schema` should suite well. (didn't know that the update time is stored there, thanks for this)

Comment: Yes, I agree, thanks for pointing this, but -- as I put in **EDIT** -- you may grant PHP only read privileges. If you take a look at the [two last comments on MySQL page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) this might not work for InnoDB.

Comment: yes, having read privileges it would be - potentially - possible to access data, which cannot being access using the mysql permission system, through a potential bug in php. :)

Comment: Yeah.. I have no idea how to access InnoDB files. In fact we need only update time of the file, not the contents. Maybe another program could check this date and return to PHP? Maybe some cron job/scheduled task would update PHP-accessible file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31464/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-voitcus)