# Using Server.MapPath with a mysql file

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently had a website with a database setup using a .mdb file.  I converted that over to a mysql database but noticed that there were several lines in the site that contained the following line:

```
Server.MapPath(@"..\_data\database.mdb")
```

Now I know this line maps the path to the database file but what I don't know is if this same function method will work now that I have a .sql file instead of a .mdb file.  I was reading online that it wouldn't work.  Initially I was just going to replace the database.mdb with the new .sql file I created which was database.sql.  That would mean the new line would look like this:

```
Server.MapPath(@"..\_data\database.sql")
```

I was hoping someone could tell me if this would work and if not, what alternatives do I have to this line? Is there an equivalent version of this through some other function?  The website is mainly coded using c# and asp.net. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of this .SQL file?. Could you post more context around that line? A MySql database is opened using a specific connection string that doesn't include a filename

Comment: Why do you need to know the path to the database file? Location can be found in the my.ini file BTW.

Comment: This gives more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947668/where-does-mysql-store-database-files-on-windows-and-what-is-the-name-of-the-fil