# How do I completely remove MySQL including cached root password from Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, windows-10, uninstallation

I need to write an installation guide for MySQL for Windows 10.  So I need to take screenshots and document steps for a 100% clean installer run.

I had MySQL already on my machine, so I uninstalled it.  I uninstalled all MySQL related components using "Add/Remove Programs" and I deleted the "C:\Program Files\MySQL" folder.

The problem is, when I run the MySQL installer and I get to the "enter root password" part, it asks me to enter the current root password.

So it seems the previous root password is cached somewhere on the system.

I don't have another clean Windows 10 machine to run the installer on, and I really don't want to re-install Windows 10 just for this.

How do I completely remove MySQL and all related components and data from Windows 10?

Comment: The root password is stored in the database itself, which you appearently didn't remove. See e.g. [Where does MySQL store database files on Windows and what is the name of the files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12947668) for where to find it (most likely at `c:\programFiles\MySQL\version number\data`)

Comment: Interesting, I thought I had deleted any `c:\program files\mysql` related folders.  I'll try again.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `c:\ProgramData\...`, not `c:\Program Files\...` (and other locations in the linked answer).

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, tomorrow I will follow the instructions in the other answer and do a thorough re-test, and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling all MySQL components using the Windows 10 uninstall, then I manually deleted the `c:\program files\mysql` and `c:\programdata\mysql` folder.

Then a full clean re-install was possible.

Thanks to @Solarflare for the pointer!