# Restoring SQL tables from .MYD, .MYI and .frm files, mysql can't find .frm files

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, restore

I recently had to re-install XAMPP on my Mac and I'm now trying to restore some SQL database tables from .MYD, .MYI and .frm files. I have tried dragging them into the file below:

```
xamppfiles/var/mysql/{database_name}
```

As per the instructions in the following links

[How to recover MySQL database from .myd, .myi, .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files)

[Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)

The table is listed in phpMyAdmin but when I try to view it I get the error below

```
#1017 - Can't find file: './{database_name}/{table_name}.frm' (errno: 13)
```

I have tried changing the permission on the .frm file and running the Unix executable file

xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server must be down while copying files.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Utilities: using the FRM Reader

- http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.com/2013/04/mysql-utilities-new-frm-reader-utility.html

Comment: Rather than just posting a link, please include content in your answer that answers the question, referring to content in the link if you want.