# I can't connect to mysql 3307 port anymore

Tags: mysql

I have a server running in 3307 port mysql, everything was doing fine, but suddenly I cannot connect to the server, not even locally. 
When I try to connect locally in the 3306 port, I can and I do see my databases, but they don't have any data inside, in fact they don't have any tables.
So I checked the data folder and there are my .frm to every single table I used to have. Do you guys have an idea about it?
Or tell me, is it possible to recover all the information just having these .frm files?

(Also, I reviewed the config file and yes, the port is 3307, but why I can't connect through it?)

Comment: Is it possible you have two instances of MySQL running?

Comment: Does it show in lsof that there is, indeed, a MySQL server running on port 3307?

Comment: Mike W
No, you know the weird thing here is that this machine is really old, so we use it just like a server, there are not other applications running, something using that port.

Comment: I haven't checked that yet, jesus that's a good one, it was friday and late, that's the first thing I'm gonna check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I had to recover my data and put it into another server :(
using this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223876/3633066
But that worked so, that's fine.