# how to recover database from .frm files?

Tags: mysql

I am new for mysql and ihave lost my database. luckily I have a data folder in which I have my .frm files of all tables.

I have searched and read about copy and paste method which I have already tried. but in mysql api there is no any tables on which I can use repair query.

so there is not any database listed in the mysql api though I have copied the .frm files in c drive folder.

please sort me out its very important to me.
thanx

Comment: May be this link useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files

Comment: @Sadikhasan I have read it bro but it would only be useful when tables are shown in api which i have pasted.

Comment: What does 'shown in API which I have pasted' mean?

Comment: @EJP I mean when i paste my .frm files in c:/..path all files which are tables should be display in phpMyAdmin when i restart my server. but it is not showing there. then how can i use repair table query if database has not generated in myadmin?