# How to import database to phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I used appache some days ago but I just changed to wamp server and I lost all my database and fortunately I searched in my pc I found some weird file, like the below Image :

[image]

is there any way to restore them to  phpmyadmin?

Comment: http://www.databaseskill.com/513135/

Comment: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/161

Comment: @PratikButani I have these folders in my local Hard C just tell me is there any way to restore them what is .MYI .MYD extension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/879268/1318946

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I just found my correct answer, I just wanna post correct answer after deeply search, I found simple answer :

just go to this path : `C:\AppServ-Backup-2008-05-10\MySQL\data` then copy database folder just copy it , then go to : `C:\AppServ\MySQL\data`  and paste here , its working perfect , have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

all Database files in xampp stored in path "xampp\mysql\data" so before uninstalling server , it is necessary to take those files in that folder as Backup, even thought if xampp version differs it will bring table collation issues, to avoid this a better way to take backupas ".sql" files...