# Restore MediaWiki site from physical files (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mediawiki

One of our servers crashed last week and it wouldn't boot. So I got a full copy of the whole file system, and restored a previous backup. Now it is up and running, but there is a problem: the most recent changes made to a MediaWiki site were lost (the backup is a month old). It's not much, just a couple of modifications to some articles here and there.

I am currently trying to restore the last MySQL tables of the site. The proper way of doing that is with the `mysqldump` command, but this is not an option because I can't boot the server, I only have the files. So I read that you can do it manually if you copy all files in `/var/lib/mysql/[dbname]`:

- [How to recover MySQL database from .myd, .myi, .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files)
- [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)
- etc

Well, I tried stopping the MySQL service and moving the files from the copy to the server, and I even granted the database user privileges again just in case, but it won't work. The site keeps showing the month old articles (yes, I have cleared the cache, and rebooted) and I don't understand why, because the files I am restoring clearly have their "last updated" field set to the date when the last changes to the wiki were made (I know that for sure).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: There might be some data in `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata` and other files in `/var/lib/mysql` outside of database directories. Have tou tried restoring whole `/var/lib/mysql`? Also, your MediaWiki might use [file cache](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:File_cache) which caches rendered pages in the filesystem, and should be disabled in your situation.

Comment: @che Thanks! The cache was not the problem, the other files were. Copying the whole directory instead of just the database did the job. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to user @che. I had to copy the whole `/var/lib/mysql` directory, not just `/var/lib/mysql/[dbname]`. Apparently some database information is also contained in those files.