# How to restore MySQL data after disk crash?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

My Ubuntu computer HD crashed, so I cant boot up anymore, I'm trying to recover my data from the hard drive by booting up using the live CD.

I can access the crashed internal hard drive by mounting it from the live CD/USB.

I have a database I want to recover, but I can't start the MySQL server since I boot from the live CD, MySQL server wont start, so I can't use the regular MySQL command line commands to do anything.

I created the database and was using it with WordPress. I spent over four months entering all this data then the computer crashed, I know I should have backed it up.

I don't even know which files are the database files, which file extensions to search for, or where the files are located on the Ubuntu.

Does anybody know where the data base files are located, and which files to copy in order to get it back after I re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: what is server fault?

Comment: It is a SE site. Here's the link: [sf]

Comment: Thanks I posted it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the slave drive. Shutdown MySQL. Copy over the content from the old /var/lib/mysql* over to the live disk. Start MySQL.

Reference :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873819&s=6ca65627adaf56a925874f898eca1c18&p=5483647#post5483647

Comment: Good God you saved me!!

Comment: Please up vote the answer if it was helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you can't run mysql and won't be able to use mysqldump, you're left with copy-pasting raw data files.

There are good answers here

[How to recover MySQL database from .myd, .myi, .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files)

Comment: I have mysql executable located in /usr/bin but there is no mysqld in there

Comment: I dont even know what command to issue in order to copy the database to another USB drive, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I tried mysqldump, but it needs the mysql server to be running, and I cant run the server because I booted off the live CD

Comment: Here's what you should be looking at. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files