# How to restore previous backup mysql db in mamp to upgraded version

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am using MAMP and tried to upgrade it to new version,

I took backup of the db and all files from htdocs folder
(Copy pasted them as backup before uninstalling)

[image]

[image]

I installed new upgraded version of mamp 4
On copying the mysql folder back, the mysql server was not starting.

After googling, I uninstalled it again and changed the previous version of mamp 3.5, 
On restoring the db, the mamp runs however no backup data table is showing the schema and data.

Comment: next time you want to make a backup use mysqldump instead of copying folders!

Comment: So all gone or anything can be still done ?

Comment: Not sure, I never had to recover from a situation like this. Can you please show the files within your folders, so I have an idea what you have there

Comment: update the ques, it has frm files

Comment: The best course of action is to install the previous version, put the folders back and create a backup with mysqldump as @lloiacono mentioned. And it may be possible that it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [mysqlfrm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqlfrm.html) to recover your backup.

> The mysqlfrm utility is designed as a recovery tool that reads .frm
>   files and produces equivalent CREATE statements from the table
>   definition data found in the file. In most cases, the generated CREATE
>   statement is usable for recreating the table on another server, or for
>   extended diagnostics.

```
mysqlfrm --diagnostic mysql/db_name/ > db_name.sql
```

Then is just a matter of importing the .sql file

If you are using windows, the mysqlfrm Utilities is not installed by default if you are using WAMP/XAMPP. So you need to install manually by downloading it from [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-install.html).

For more details on how to proceed check this [step by step tutorial](http://www.smarttutorials.net/import-mysql-table-frm-files-using-mysqlfrm-utilities/).

Comment: Thanks !! I am able to recover schema, however any way to restore data as well. Its not showing any data.

Comment: Since I never did this I am not sure, but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files