# Restore MySQL database from a broken hard disk

Tags: php, mysql, database

A few days ago my hard drive gone bad so I had to replace my computer with a new hard disk, I wasn't able to go into the OS at all, therefore I couldn't backup my MySQL database, however I managed to saved the whole xampp folder from the broken hard disk.

However when I copied and paste my database folder in mysql folder to the new hard disk with a newly installed xampp, I couldn't open my tables, it shows error "#1932 - Table doesn't exist in engine", so I tried copying the whole data folder inside the mysql, and MySQL service won't start.

I have also tried copying the ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1 into the new drive, then I could not even log in into phpmyadmin, saying "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." Can't connect to mysql through cmd to saying "1006 unknown error".

Now how do I salvage my database from the old drive ?

All suggestions are greatly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: follow this steps you will be able to recover all your tables from your .frm and .myd files https://stackoverflow.com/a/879268/6582942

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to just run xampp from the old folder (without the newly installed xampp)?  I have read in a forum that this is possible if you installed the non-zip version of xampp.  If you are having trouble with the old folder on a new version of xampp, I would just try running the copied xampp and see what happens...