# MySql server logs error after installation

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySql fresh installation version 5.17.9
  Mysql services started nicely and giving good throughput
But in server logs, I got this type of error:

```
InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/engine_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of          InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
 Cannot open table mysql/help_category from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
Cannot open table mysql/help_keyword from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/help_relation from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/help_topic from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
 Cannot open table mysql/innodb_table_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.    
 Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
 Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
 Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
Cannot open table mysql/time_zone from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.   
 Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_name from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_transition from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.  
 Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_transition_type from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
```

Please help me how to fix such issues without restoring database from dump?

Answer (score 0):

As you said its a fresh install, but it doesn't look so.. maybe the cause is not known :P

Solution is to delete those `.frm` files manually (they are often called orphan files).

For more info..

see [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html)
and [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files)

Comment: But how will restore that table for MySql . Can you help me in this? @Manoj Shukla

Comment: This is for Innodb engine and i'm not getting actual answer from this! @Manoj

Comment: @SAMAB so which database engine u r using??

Comment: Innodb Engine and Your answer is for MyISAM storage engine @Manoj Shukla

Comment: try following this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql and let me know if it works.. cuz it looks like that issue is with installation and/or permissions.. and sorry for the late reply, was a bit busy. ;)

Comment: if you are unsure abt above process, try creating a new db user as the link says so that we can identify what the issue is. :)