# How to Restore the mysql database file in new databse on centos 7

Tags: mysql, database, restore

I have one database file content. I need to import this file into the new database. I moved the old database in /var/lib/mysql folder. But showing only database name. please, anyone, help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover MySQL database from .myd, .myi, .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files)

Comment: I tried But I can't export the database. While exporting the database it showing No tables found in the database.

Comment: I guess you use mysql because of folder name. Do you still have access to the original database? If yes, use `mysqldump databasename > db.sql` to export from old database, and `mysql databasename < db.sql` to import to new one. Search the internet to find a couple of examples.