# WAMP: using .MYD, .frm , .MYI , db.opt to restore database

Tags: mysql

Some days ago I forced to uninstall my wamp cause I didn't have any access to phpmyadmin, so that I just copy the MySQL folder of that damaged wamp before uninstalling to have databases to reuse them later

Now I installed a new version of wamp and when I pasted the databases file such as .MYD, .frm , .MYI , db.opt in the data folder of MySQL wamp, in phpmyadmin I can see the tables but when I wanted to see the columns I got this error:

```
#1146 - Table 'Databasename.table_name' doesn't exist
```

[image: error screen shot]

Please tell me whats wrongs with them? is there any way to use my old databases? If attaching database files is needed to tell me to do that...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files which seems to discuss exactly what you want. Also, can't see why you have tagged this with php (phpmyadmin is an application /written/ in php, php as a programming language is not relevant here, nor is phpmyadmin really).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luckily the problem solved by my self!
I did it in the simplest way! just deleted last MySQL folder which was the newer version of MySQL and pasted that previous MySQL folder in it, then just edit the **my.ini** file and correct the wrong address and folder names

**Don't forget to restart the services**

for my self, there was no need to do something with MySQL command line which some friends said to do
if you think deleting MySQL folder could be riskable install a new wamp which has got as the same version of previous damage databases...
So the version of both databases **have to be the same**, especially when your database engines are InnoDB
hope be helpful